# React Native this2.state error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, setstate

I am trying to take the response from a GET request (which is an array of objects), and set it's state to an array 'templates', so that I can later access it with this.state.templates, like so:

```
  fetch('https://tiy-warmup.herokuapp.com/api/templates?token=' + 
  token)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(response => this.setState({templates: response}))
  // .then(response => console.log(response))
```

When I have the setState line commented out and just console log the response, I get the correct array back, so I know that my fetch is good. However, when I try to run the setState line, I get this error:

```
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
_this2.setState is not a function
```

What would be a solution to getting around this error and being able to use this.state.templates in the render?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wherever you're using this fetch, either bind the function or change to arrow function. `this` is not being bound to the component so `this.setState` is throwing an error. The unhandled promise rejection error is showing because you do not have a catch statement set up to handle errors.

Answer (score 0):

`_this2.setState is not a function`, usually, your this is not the ref of you Component, start your debugger and carefully check what is `this` ref to. I guess you may use `bind` or `const self = this` to solve this problem.

take a look at this post may help you, https://www.sitepoint.com/bind-javascripts-this-keyword-react/

Answer (score -1):

> Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection

This error happens because you're not implementing `catch` on your promise

```
.catch(error  => {
  console.log('There has been a problem with your fetch operation: '+ error.message);
});
```